# How to import a plugin using ES6? (Getting ReferenceError: Plugin is not defined)

Tags: javascript, webpack

Trying to wrap my head around Webpack. I was able to set it up and get it working (combines my scripts and styles just fine), but I'm having trouble with a lazy loading plugin called bLazy, which I installed via npm. Here's the code in the file that I've defined as the entry point:

```
// Stylesheets

import './style.scss';

// Scripts

import 'salvattore'; 
import 'blazy'; 

var bLazy = new Blazy(); // This is the documented way to initialize bLazy.
```

I am getting the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: Blazy is not defined`. The Salvattore plugin, which is self-initializing, works fine. I'm also using jQuery, but bLazy is written in Javascript, so there shouldn't be any conflicting issues.

What am I doing wrong?

**+++ UPDATE +++**

I've changed the way I posed my question because apparently it's about ES6 and not Webpack, like I thought it was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this 
`import Blazy from 'blazy'`

Comment: Hey, thanks, that does fix the error. But what if I have to pass in some arguments? For example how would I translate this: `var bLazy = new Blazy({ selector: '.lazy' });`

Comment: You have just imported whole class `Blazy`,rest of the code stays the same.You have wrote it by yourself `var bLazy = new Blazy({ selector: '.lazy' });`

Answer (score 1):

In the script you want to import you should "export" a value, like this:

```
class Blazy {...}

export default Blazy;
```

Then in script where you want to use it, you need to "import" this value:

```
import Blazy from './blazy'; // Note the path in quotes is relative to your current script file

let blazy = new Blazy();
```